# Editing for missing dollar signs

Tags: discussion, editing, character-limit

So, I'm a new user and trying to figure out how things work around here.   I saw a post in which someone forgot to put one of their math equations between dollar signs, so it came out in raw LateX rather than in a readable form.

I saw an 'edit' button, and went "I'll just be nice and edit this in".  Saw that it'd then enter a queue to have the edit be confirmed, which is fine...but then when I went to try to submit it,  I got an error message saying edits had to be at least 6 characters long.  I can see why one might not want people going in to edit minor spelling mistakes,  but it seems like this is a pretty common edit to want to make....should I just put a comment in for the original poster to fix,  or is there some other way around this, or...?

Comment: See also some older posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length and also the two posts shown there among linked questions (on the right).

Answer (score 5):

My suggestions, in decreasing order of preference.

1. Try to improve the post in other ways. Rare is a question that cannot be  improved. Even rarer is an impeccable question by a user who forgets dollar signs.
2. Leave the post as is. Some 2k user will notice the missing markup and fix it.
3. Work around the restriction in some way: insert whitespace into a formula, or invisible HTML entities in text `&nbsp;`, etc. Adding an empty formula is probably the worst option in terms of rendering speed.

Comment: There are some posts I've seen that were well-written, but the user thought that MathJax would render `\begin{align}\end{align}` like LaTeX does (and thus they didn't enter dollar signs).  I thought 2k users were still subject to character edit limits... but maybe not.  (Aside: do HTML comments work for the character limit? I don't want to test it and bump a post by accident.)

Comment: huh.  I guess MathJax made the dollar signs on align environments optional now.  Nevermind about that.

Comment: #3 is terrible, in my opinion. There's no point in going through the whole edit review process just for adding two dollar signs.

Comment: 1. is often not possible. I almost got banned from editing because of some 2/3 edits that added $s and changed the grammar.

Answer (score -1):

The workaround, which should only be used when absolutely necessary, is to write `${}{}{}$` at the bottom.  It renders invisibly.

Comment: Thanks, working on learning the ropes :)

Comment: Please don't. At least use `&nbsp;`. Including junk mathjax slows the page down for everyone.

Comment: Fair enough--I'll leave this answer here so people can see that it's not recommended.